# Права доступа на конфиг exim (freebsd)

Tags: email, exim, freebsd

Вечер добрый!

Подскажите, есть основной конфиг эксима, который, как в принципе и рекомендуют имеет права 0600 и принадлежит root:wheel

Более того, сервис при запуске это проверяет, и пишет *Exim configuration file /usr/local/etc/exim/configure has the wrong owner, group, or mode*, если это не так.

Приколы начинаются, когда пытаюсь запустить эксим не под рутом (изменены опции при сборке).

Он продолжает проверять, чтоб конфиг был под нужными правами, но МТА, который запускается для раскладывания очереди кидает ошибку: *failed to open configuration file /usr/local/etc/exim/configure: Permission denied (euid=1004 egid=6)*, что в принципе вполне логично))

Письмо обрабатывается (принимается, ложиться в /var/spool/input/....):При тестировании exim -bT postmaster пишет, нормально local_delivery.

```
   2012-06-05 16:52:56 no IP address found for host 53-13xxxxxxxxxxx (during SMTP   connection from [xxxxxxxx13.53])   2012-06-05 16:52:56 1Sbx04-000MrW-55 <= postmaster@xxxxxxxxxxxxx H=(xxxxxxxxx) [xxxxxxxx13.53] P=esmtps X=TLSv1:AES128-SHA:128 S=2631 id=005a01cd433b$8c64a530$a52def90$@xxxxxxxxxxxxx from <postmaster@xxxxxxxxxxxxx> for postmaster@xxxxxxxxxxxxx   2012-06-05 16:52:56 failed to open configuration file /usr/local/etc/exim/configure: Permission denied (euid=1004 egid=6)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, чего я не понимаю в этой жизни ?))

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вопрос можно закрывать.

Answer (score 2):

Методом научного тыка подобрался ответ:

Права на конфиг нужно делать 0640 root:mail

То, есть, группа, не рутовая, а под которой работает setuid'ный exim, и этой группе разрешено чтение. Этого достаточно для МТА, и проверка это позволяет.